# How to translate formik ErrorMessage with React i18next

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have following components:

```js
import { Formik, Form, useField, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import Select from "react-select";

const iceCreamOptions = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

const FormSelect = ({ name, options }) => {
  const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(name);
  return (
    <>
      <Select
        name={name}
        value={field.value}
        onChange={(value) => helpers.setValue(value)}
        options={options}
        onBlur={() => helpers.setTouched(true)}
      />
      <ErrorMessage name={name} />
    </>
  );
};

const initialValues = {
  icecream: null
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  icecream: Yup.object()
    .shape({
      value: Yup.string(),
      label: Yup.string()
    })
    .required("Please select a value")
    .nullable()
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
    >
      {(props) => {
        return (
          <Form>
            <FormSelect name="icecream" options={iceCreamOptions} />
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Now I would like to add tranlations to my application, so i will use React i18next.
Basic example is something like that:

```js
const { t } = useTranslation();

<p>{t('message')}</p>
```

Now, How can i use this translations with my ErrorMessage component?
I am sure, I can't do something like that :D

```js
t(<ErrorMessage name={name} />)
```

So if there is no way to handle it with `t` and `ErrorMessage`, I think I need to do following thing:

```js
{meta.touched && meta.error ? (
  <div className="error">{t(meta.error)}</div>
) : null}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Yup.typeError() like this.

```
    const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  icecream: Yup.object()
    .shape({
      value: Yup.string(),
      label: Yup.string()
    }).TypeError(' Your msg translated here')
    .required("Please select a value")
    .nullable()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can directly translate the `validationSchema` like this;

```
const validationSchema = (t) => Yup.object().shape({
  icecream: Yup.object()
    .shape({
      value: Yup.string(),
      label: Yup.string()
    })
    .required(t("RequiredValueTranslation"))
    .nullable()
});
```

and use it

```
const [t] = useTranslation()
const schema = () => validationSchema(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the `render` function from `formik`, but in the same way you would have to change the `yup` message to be the translation key.

[ErrorMessage-render](https://formik.org/docs/api/errormessage#render)

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  icecream: Yup.object()
    .shape({
      value: Yup.string(),
      label: Yup.string()
    })
    .required("requiredTranslationKey")
    .nullable()
});
```

and then, in the component body

```js
<ErrorMessage name={name} render={key => t(key)} />
```